# Is there a way to extract properties of style using the xml file of Word doc?

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I wanted to extract some of the properties for example outlinelevel of style "heading1". But i really dont know how to do it i tried, using just javascript in office API but this too does not worked.

Like I said I used a office.js to manipulate my document but it didnt work to extract style properties from it.

```
function stylePropertiesCatch() {
    Word.run((context) => {
      var heading1Style = context.document.styles.getByTitle("heading1");
      heading1Style.load("font, color, size, spacing, outlineLevel");
      return context.sync().then(function () {
        console.log("Font: " + heading1Style.font.name);
        console.log("Color: " + heading1Style.color);
        console.log("Size: " + heading1Style.size);
        console.log("Spacing: " + heading1Style.spacing.before + ", " + heading1Style.spacing.after);
        console.log("Outline Level: " + heading1Style.outlineLevel);
      });
    });
  }
```

this is how this function looks like in test #21 it seams that the cotntext.document.styles is not a object from which i can get a significant style. I am trying to manipulate now a xml form of this file and i can get a name and basedOn prop from a style but inside this file there is just maybe 4/5 w:style tags and other styles are in lsdException tags whch dont have any props which i can extract I saw some of tutorails how to see where there are style props in it and it seams that i need to modify those styles to get theirs properties bcs otherwise they have default props. But what about the default props where i can find them or from where can i extract them ?

this is how lsdException tag looks like in xml file

`<w:lsdException w:name="heading 1" w:uiPriority="9" w:qFormat="1"/>`

and this is how style tag looks like in xml file

```
<w:style w:type="character" w:default="1" w:styleId="DefaultParagraphFont">
<w:name w:val="Default Paragraph Font"/>
<w:uiPriority w:val="1"/>
<w:semiHidden/>
<w:unhideWhenUsed/>
</w:style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are some APIs in preview which can extract styles and corresponding properties. You can use [Document.getStyles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.document?view=word-js-preview#word-word-document-getstyles-member(1)) API to get styles from the document, and filter with [SectionCollection.getByName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.stylecollection?view=word-js-preview#word-word-stylecollection-getbyname-member(1)) API. In your case, the code should be

```
await Word.run(async (context) => {
    let heading1Style = context.document.getStyles().getByName("Heading 1");
    heading1Style.load("font, font/color, font/size, paragraphFormat/lineSpacing, paragraphFormat/outlineLevel");
    await context.sync();
    console.log(heading1Style.font);
    console.log(heading1Style.font.color);
    console.log(heading1Style.font.size);
    console.log(heading1Style.paragraphFormat.lineSpacing);
    console.log(heading1Style.paragraphFormat.outlineLevel);
  });
```

For more properties and methods about style, please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.style?view=word-js-preview.

Comment: It should work but I dont know why it gives me an error saying that getStyles() property dont exist on document object.

Comment: As you may see in the document,  Document.getStyles() API is still in preview. To use this API, please ensure 1. You are using Word desktop (not Word online). 2. Your Word build version is later than 16.0.16130.20332. 3. Your office.js reference URL is changed to https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js. Please note, currently, you can't use Style APIs in a production environment.

Comment: Do I have to change anything else ? I mean I did everything that You said. Check version, Use desktop version and change my office.js reference in libraries but it still doesnt work. This time tho it is giving me another error. **Uncaught (in promise) RichApi.Error: GeneralException.** and not That getStyles is not a function. I did the test in the visual studio code version addin and it is giving me a error in file **word-win32-16-01.js:25:261201**. Any thoughts ? maybe it isint finished yet ?